# XMLLite ignore encoding

Tags: c++, xmllite

I have to read XML files in C++ and we are using `XMLLite` the problem I have is that the first line of my XML specifies the encoding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15"?>
```

and when I try to parse the file with XMLLite, I'm getting the error `MX_E_ENCODINGSIGNATURE`. If I remove the encoding part, the XML parses fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

So is it possible to programmatically tell XMLLite to ignore the encoding resp. what other options do I have?

One solution would be to write my own input stream class and suppress this header, and inject the short version, but it would be nicer to have a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the documentation says that XMLLite can not handle different encodings it seems that you can go around this by using `IMultiLanguage2`, which is mentioned in the documentation but no example is given.

So here is how to enable it:

```
#include <mlang.h>

XMLLiteReader::XMLLiteReader(void)
{
    mLanguage = NULL;
    mXMLLiteReader = NULL;
    mCOMInitialized = false;

    HRESULT hr;
    if(CoInitialize(NULL) != S_OK)
        return;
    mCOMInitialized = true;

    if((hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CMultiLanguage, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMultiLanguage2, (void **)&mLanguage)) != S_OK)
        return;

    hr = CreateXmlReader(__uuidof(IXmlReader), (void**) &mXMLLiteReader, NULL);
    if(hr != S_OK)
    {
        mXMLLiteReader = NULL;
        return;
    }

    hr = mXMLLiteReader->SetProperty(XmlReaderProperty_MultiLanguage, (LONG_PTR)mLanguage);
}
```